# Method being skipped?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

Ok. The problem I'm having is a little difficult to explain, but essentially my issue is the method that is responsible for filling a dataset is being skipped. The debugger hits the line of code in question, but skips right over it. No chance of stepping into or what not.

```
// Class A
private myTableDS _dsTable; // myTableDS.xsd
private classB _clsB; 

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
   if (_dsTable == null)
   {
       _dsTable = _clsB.LoadThisTable(); // The culprit
   }

   // More logic here. Mindblowing. It is. 
}



// Class B
public myTableDS LoadThisTable() 
{
   // Magic here
}
```

So the debugger hits the line `_dsTable = _clsB.LoadThisTable();` and jumps out. Taking me back to the next line in the code that invoked "onload" in the first place. So any and all logic beneath `_dsTables = _ASIO.LoadASTables();` is skipped.

Thoughts?

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint somewhere in `// More logic here. Mindblowing. It is. `? Are you doing any multithreading/asyc stuff?

Comment: When do you ever initialize _clsB?

Comment: I just read a similar question the other day, and I think the explanation was that, for complicated reasons, .NET catches and swallows exceptions thrown in OnLoad for apps running in 64-bit mode.  I'll look for the question or the article it linked to, but look for things that might throw exceptions.  For instance, is _clsB ever null in OnLoad?

Comment: Here's the article: http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/

Comment: Perhaps _clsB is null?

Comment: To see if an exception is being thrown, try wrapping the entire guts of OnLoad in a try/catch.

Comment: Try doing a "Rebuild Solution" in case your files are out of sync.

Comment: wow. that was quick. alright here's some answers...
@tnw - yes. i set a breakpoint there to confirm that that section of code is being skipped.

and yes, _clsB is null because I only want to fill it once.

Comment: @adv12 - I will take a look at that article here in a bit. thanks for the info.

Comment: @RickL - I was wondering if that had something to do with it.. because I ran into an issue with that this morning. To resolve it I had to rebuild each project individually within the solution and that seemed to have worked out for me.

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey - Wow. I wasn't initializing _clsB. Thanks for the extra eyes guys. This noob is going to go read up on OOP 101. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when the debugger is skipping code, it has something to do with threading (which doesn't appear to be the case here), a type load exception (missing assembly), or a different version of the code being deployed than what is being debugged.

If the latter cases are the problem, the solution is making sure the very latest assemblies are actually deployed to the environment you're debugging.

Also, try putting a Debbugger.Launch() statement in myTableDS.LoadThisTable() and setting Visual Studio up so that the debugger breaks when exceptions are thrown (not just unhandled).